# Unity prefab set a new rotation as rotation 0?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

New with NavMesh. Want to use a navmesh with a car model. But when `set destination` is called, it rotates the model to 0 degree which is the back side of the model car. I tried to set it to a new rotation of 180deg and make that a new prefab, but that keeps the old rotation reference and navmesh agent rotates it back. I need to keep the front side toward the destination.

```
NavMeshAgent agent;
public Camera camera;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            agent.destination = hit.point;
        }

    }
    
}
```

TIA.

Comment: normally you would use a parent game object so that 0 is forwards, irrelevant of how the model was designed

Comment: @BugFinder Any hint on, How to make the navmesh agent radius as big as the model?

Comment: Change the settings on the agent?